# Gwt compiling error: unable to find entry point when it's not in src/main/java

Tags: gwt, compilation, entry-point

I have an error compiling my app:

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.mycompany.myapp.MyAppMocked
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.mycompany.myapp.client.mock.MockEntryPoint'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.mycompany.myapp.client.mock.MockEntryPoint' is really what you meant
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
```

In my .gwt.xml, I have:

```
<entry-point class="com.mycompany.myapp.client.mock.MockEntryPoint" />
```

The problem occurs when I put MockEntryPoint.java in src/mocked/java instead of src/main/java.

I need to have both directories to exclude everything in src/mocked/java when compiling the "no-mock" version.

If I move MockEntryPoint.java to src/main/java, the compilation will succeed with no error. In both cases, the class MockEntryPoint is in the package "com.mycompany.myapp.client.mock".

How can I tell gwt to look for my entry class in src/mocked/java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a Maven project, you need to add `src/mocked/java` as a source folder. In Maven, it has to be done using the `build-helper-maven-plugin`'s [`add-source`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) mojo.

---

But there's little to no reason to have that `src/mocked` hierarchy:

- you can put everything in `src/main` and just compile the GWT module you need/want (set the `module` or `modules` configuration property for the `gwt-maven-plugin` accordingly)
- if you want them clearly separated, Maven wants you to use distinct Maven modules/projects. You don't want to fight against Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Replace statement `<source path='main'/>` with `<source path='mocked'/>` in your .gwt.xml
Then compiler will know which directory to choose for compilation.

I hope it helps.